# Eclipse RCP: Get notified when IWorkbenchPreferencePage is left

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have implemented two custom `IWorkbenchPreferencePage`'s and they are working as expected. Basically Page1 shows different information based on the selections made in Page2. The problem is that I have to close (explicitly save) the preference dialog to see the changes of Page2 reflect in Page1.

Now I was wondering if there is some kind of mechanism that would allow me to do something (In my case save information on the open preference page) once a `IWorkbenchPreferencePage` gets left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `okToLeave` method which is called when a different page is selected.

The default implementation of this in `PreferencePage` is:

```java
@Override
public boolean okToLeave() {
    return isValid();
}
```

You can also use the

```java
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
```

method which is called when the page is made visible and when it is hidden (be sure to call `super.setVisible` in your override).

Comment: Thank you geg, works well! I was just curious, do you know why the init(IWorkbench workbench) and the createFieldEditors() method is called only the first time a PreferencePage gets opened? I'm looking for a method that gets called everytime when I open the page not only the first time.

Comment: The page is only created once. The `setVisible` method is used to show or hide the page controls after that. Added that to the answer.